# Prove that a particular matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, pseudoinverse

Let $A$ and $V$ be positive semidefinite matrices, and let $U$ be an orthogonal matrix, partitioned columnwise:

$$U = \begin{bmatrix} U_1 & U_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Consider the matrix

$$M = A + U_1^T V U_1 - U_1^T V U_2 (U_2^T V U_2)^+ U_2^T V U_1$$

where $X^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse of matrix $X$.

**Conjecture:** Assume $A + U_1^T V U_1 > 0$. Then $M > 0$.

I would like to either prove the conjecture or find a counterexample. The following examples lead me to believe that the conjecture is true, but a proof has remained elusive:

1) If $V = 0$, then we must have $A > 0$ for the assumption in the conjecture to hold. Then $M = A > 0$.

2) If $A = 0$ and $U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, with $V = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ or $V = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $M = 1 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture is false. Here is a counterexample:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad V = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \qquad U_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad U_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $A + U_1^T V U_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} > 0$, but $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.